# No constructor with 1 argument defined in class 'UserDaoImpl' [config set: myProject/web-context]

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-3, web-inf, hibernate.cfg.xml

Error Message: No constructor with 1 argument defined in class 'UserDaoImpl' [config set: myProject/web-context]

After reading few other similar questions, verified that in the class all the constructors are named with the same class name, were of type public access modifier and there is no return type in the constructor.

Still this error message was shown in the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<bean id="userDaoImpl" class="com.company.users.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>        
</bean>
```

And, here is the constructor code in UserDaoImpl class.

```
public UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super();
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

@Gusman [Addition]

Hibernate session factory

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>/resources/hibernate/User.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>/resources/hibernate/UserRole.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

@hooknc [Addition]

This is the setter code in UserDaoImpl file.

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

Comment: my hibernate is a bit rusty, but *ref="sessionFactory"* shouldn't be *ref="SessionFactory"*?

Comment: @Gusman Same ref id is been used as mentioned in hibernate-cfg.xml file bean id, i.e. id="sessionFactory". And the same code is been added in the question for your reference.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you look more closely at your spring config file, you'll see you're trying to set a property on your `UserDaoImpl`.  Based on your `UserDaoImpl` class you have a constructor that takes a `SessionFactory`.  The error is being caused because spring is trying to call a zero parameter constructor on `UserDaoImpl` but there isn't one.

There is only the constructor that takes a `SessionFactory`.

If you change the spring config file to use a constructor value instead, everything should work out:

```
<bean id="userDaoImpl" class="com.company.users.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have tested your code, but same error exists. Setter & Getter method code is already there in the UserDaoImpl file and the same is been added in the question for your reference.

Comment: Updated the answer to (hopefully) be a bit more clear on what is actually happening and why.